# `find -delete` Erased Everything

Tags: find

I'm not too familiar with `find` and managed to delete a ton of files by accident.  I was wondering if anyone more experienced could explain where I went wrong.

---

I wanted to clean up all of the `.DS_Store` and `._.DS_Store` files that my MacBook's Finder was barfing all over my Raspbian samba share.

- I have a hard drive attached to my raspberry pi, with some symlinks
  in my home folder to the mounting point, hence the `-L`.
- Some of the folders are owned by system users (e.g. apache) hence the
  `sudo`.

I ran the following to make sure that `find` was targeting the right files:

```
hydraxan@raspberry:~ $ sudo find -L . -maxdepth 255 -name \*DS_Store\*
./.DS_Store
./Downloads/USBHDD1/._.DS_Store
./Downloads/USBHDD1/.DS_Store
./Downloads/USBHDD1/backups/ALAC/._.DS_Store
./Downloads/USBHDD1/backups/ALAC/Jeff Van Dyck - Assault Android Cactus OST/._.DS_Store
./Downloads/USBHDD1/backups/ALAC/Jeff Van Dyck - Assault Android Cactus OST/.DS_Store
./Downloads/USBHDD1/backups/ALAC/.DS_Store
./Downloads/USBHDD1/backups/._.DS_Store
./Downloads/USBHDD1/backups/.DS_Store
./Downloads/USBHDD1/backups/OriginalMusic/._.DS_Store
./Downloads/USBHDD1/backups/OriginalMusic/.DS_Store
./Downloads/USBHDD1/backups/OriginalMusic/FLAC/.DS_Store
./Downloads/USBHDD1/backups/Storage/._.DS_Store
./Downloads/USBHDD1/backups/Storage/.DS_Store
./Downloads/OriginalMusic/._.DS_Store
./Downloads/OriginalMusic/.DS_Store
./Downloads/OriginalMusic/FLAC/.DS_Store
./Downloads/ALAC/._.DS_Store
./Downloads/ALAC/Jeff Van Dyck - Assault Android Cactus OST/._.DS_Store
./Downloads/ALAC/Jeff Van Dyck - Assault Android Cactus OST/.DS_Store
./Downloads/ALAC/.DS_Store
```

All looks good!

I then added the `-delete` flag to cause `find` to remove the files it found:

```
hydraxan@raspberry:~ $ sudo find -L . -maxdepth 255 -delete -name \*DS_Store\*
find: cannot delete `./Documents': Not a directory
find: cannot delete `./Pictures': Not a directory
find: cannot delete `./Music': Not a directory
```

Once I realized it was trying to delete my symlinks for some reason, I punched `Ctrl+C` and saved about half the data.

Documents, Pictures, and Music are toast.  It was probably working on my giant Downloads folder that I put nearly everything in.

---

Why did `find` delete all those files?  Did I put `-delete` in the wrong spot?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your answer is in `find` manpage.

The delete option is processed before your name filter.

```
       -delete
          Delete files; true if removal succeeded.  If the removal failed,
          an  error message is issued.  If -delete fails, find's exit sta‐
          tus will be nonzero (when it eventually exits).  Use of  -delete
          automatically turns on the -depth option.

          Warnings:  Don't  forget that the find command line is evaluated
          as an expression, so putting -delete first will make find try to
          delete everything below the starting points you specified.  When
          testing a find command line that you later intend  to  use  with
          -delete,  you should explicitly specify -depth in order to avoid
          later surprises.  Because -delete  implies  -depth,  you  cannot
          usefully use -prune and -delete together.
```

You could have moved the delete option as the last one of your command

Alternatively, you could have used something like

```
find /path -name "*pattern*" | xargs rm -f
```

or

```
find /path -name "*pattern*" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: +1 except `xargs`, `exec` don't solve the problem at all (same pitfall, if you add -print0 or -exec at the beginning instead of the end).

Comment: Ah, I misread the `man` page.  I thought it was saying that `-delete` needs to be after the path ("starting point"), not the pattern.

Comment: @Hydraxan14 the point is that things are processed left to right so your command was `find things which are less than 256 directory levels down and delete them and whose name contains DS_Store`

Comment: @icarus Paraphrasing the command like that helps me understand it a lot better.  Thanks!  I'm used to other *nix commands which don't care where flags go.

Comment: @Hydraxan14 Many commands cares about the order of command line flags.  Compare, for example, `ls -1 -l` with `ls -l -1`.

Answer (score 1):

The basic principle of the command line of `find` is “if condition and condition and … then action”. Note that the action comes last — it's quite different from the format of calling a command which is “action object object …”.

For example, `find . -name \*DS_Store\* -delete` means “if the name matches `*DS_Store*` then delete”. If you reverse the condition and the action, the `-delete` action has no condition behind it, so it's applied unconditionally.

The reason why `find . -delete -name \*DS_Store\*` is not a syntax error is that actions are also conditions. The `-delete` action is a true condition if it succeeds, and is false if it fails (e.g. due to a lack of permissions). For example, `find . -name somethingorother -delete -print` prints the names of the files that are successfully deleted.

The reason why `find -name \*DS_Store\*` is not a syntax error is that if there is no action, then there is an implicit `-print` action. It was designed this way because printing is a very common choice of action.

(Note that while my answer does not contain an outright lie, it does simplify some things. There are features of `find` that the explanations in my answer does not cover, in particular the `!` and `-o` logical operators.)